# save excel file to server using php

Tags: php, excel, export, export-to-excel

I am retrieving data from database and exporting it to excel with the below code, from this i can export to excel and saving the file from browser.

```
$sql_select= "my query";
$queryRes = mysql_query($sql_select);

$header = "Country" . "\t";
$header .= "Network" . "\t";
$header .= "MCC" . "\t";
$header .= "MNC" . "\t";
$header .= "ClientPrice" . "\t";
$header .= "Currency" . "\t";

$data = '';
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryRes)){
$row1 = array();
$row1[] = $row['country'];
$row1[] = $row['networkname'];
$row1[] = $row['mcc'];
$row1[] = $row['mnc'];
$row1[] = $row['clientprice'];
$row1[] = $row['currency'];
$data .= join("\t", $row1)."\n";
//$data= $first_name."\t";
//$data .= $row['originator']."\t";
}

header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=expot.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data"; 
exit();
```

I am using the below code to save the excel file to this location "/pricelists/example.xls"

```
file_put_contents("/pricelists/example.xls",$data);
print "$header\n$data";
```

It is showing warning

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/pricelists/example.xls) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream:
```

Can anyone guide me how to fix this thanks?

Answer (score 3):

Does your file exists at the path /pricelists/example.xls?

Using relative path to the file may solve the issue.

```
file_put_contents("pricelists/example.xls",$data);
```

Comment: No, it is not exist. The function "file_put_contents" should create the file if it desn't exist.

Comment: If you're trying to save to a directory that file_put_contents() doesn't have permission to write to, such as `/pricelists` (remembering that this is from the filesystem root - `/`), would you expect it to ignore those permissions and still write the file? creating a directory if it didn't exist? - What price security?

Comment: the permission for this folder "pricelists" is 777

Comment: @arok - yes that's all very well, but are you expecting to write to a folder called `pricelists` within your website or on the root of the filesystem?

Answer (score -1):

If you use Windows:

Go to the "Properties" of your folder containing the output file, disable read-only, go to the "Security" index, click on "Edit" and then on "Add", type "Everyone" and give full permissions and apply the settings.

If you use Linux or you have an hired webserver:

Give the full permission with CHMOD 777 /your/folder/ or with your FTP application.

Comment: Never use `chmod 777`. Why open up execute permission to everyone?